# SQL JOINS and naming joined column

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a Products table and Downloads table.

The Downloads table has 4 fields, ID, Name, Category and Download

The Products table has 3 fields specific to Downloads: Downloads, Order Guides and Submittal Sheets.  Each one of these fields stores the ID of the record from the Downloads table.  There will never be the same Download ID value for these 3 fields in the Product table.

I have the follow SQL statement:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, product_download, product_submittal, product_ordering_guide, product_status, tbl_downloads.download_id, tbl_downloads.download_name
FROM tbl_products
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads ON tbl_products.product_download=tbl_downloads.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads ON tbl_products.product_submittal=tbl_downloads.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads ON tbl_products.product_order_guide=tbl_downloads.download_id
```

It generates the following error:

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_downloads'
```

This error makes sense and I know it was going to happen, but I don't know how to fix it.  I need to add an Alias, but not sure where.

If I remove the last two JOIN statements, everything works as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use unique aliases if you are joining the same table multiple times:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, 
    product_download, product_submittal, 
    product_ordering_guide, product_status, 
    d1.download_id DownloadId, 
    d1.download_name DownloadName,
    d2.download_id SubmittalDownloadId, 
    d2.download_name SubmittalDownloadName,
    d3.download_id GuideDownloadId, 
    d3.download_name GuideDownloadName
FROM tbl_products
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads d1
    ON tbl_products.product_download=d1.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads d2
    ON tbl_products.product_submittal=d2.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads d3
    ON tbl_products.product_order_guide=d3.download_id
```

For example I used `d1`, `d2` and `d3` but you might want to be more descriptive in your aliases so it is clear what each join is doing, like this:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, 
    product_download, product_submittal, 
    product_ordering_guide, product_status, 
    download.download_id DownloadId, 
    download.download_name DownloadName,
    submittal.download_id SubmittalDownloadId, 
    submittal.download_name SubmittalDownloadName,
    guide.download_id GuideDownloadId, 
    guide.download_name GuideDownloadName
FROM tbl_products
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads download
    ON tbl_products.product_download=download.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads submittal
    ON tbl_products.product_submittal=submittal.download_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_downloads guide
    ON tbl_products.product_order_guide=guide.download_id
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is the "AS" implied here?  Why don't I have to preface the download information with the table name in the SELECT statement

Comment: @Brett The `AS` is not required to alias a table.  Once you use an alias, you have to reference the table with the alias in the select, where, etc. :)